# Reasons for UIimagePickerControler make crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender
{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imgPicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }


}

-(IBAction)btnCancelCamera_Clicked:(id)sender{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}




-(IBAction)btnCaptureImage_Clicked:(id)sender{
    [imgPicker takePicture];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [self savePhotoProcess:info];


}


-(void)savePhotoProcess:(NSDictionary *)imgObject
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger appcnt = [defaults integerForKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];
    pickedImage = [imgObject objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    pickedImage = [self scaleAndRotateImage:pickedImage];



    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0.7);

    imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",appcnt];

    [imageArray addObject:imageName];

    path = [SAVEDIMAGE_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];






    pickedImage=nil;
    imageData=nil;
    imgPicker=nil;

}



- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image 
{ 
    int width = image.size.width;
    int height = image.size.height;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    CGRect imageRect;

    if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationUp 
       || image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationDown) 
            {
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height); 
            }
    else 
            {
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width); 
            }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationLeft) 
            {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -width);
            }
    else if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationRight) 
            {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, - M_PI / 2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
            } 
    else if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationUp) 
            {
            //DO NOTHING
            }
    else if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationDown) 
            {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, width, height);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
            }

    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    UIImage *img1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return (img1);
}
```

I have imagePickerController in my app.It is keep crashing when tested by client.I could not simultate that crash.please somebody tell what are the reasons that cause crash so i can simulate that problem.any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance.

Comment: It'll be difficult without crashlogs.

Comment: is there any problem with my code?

Comment: pickedImage=nil;
imageData=nil;
imgPicker=nil;

I don't think that You need to do this in photo saving. Also, I think that issu can be in imgPicker=nil; because Your image picker can be deleted before it's view will be dismissed.

Comment: I would recommend you implement `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()` in your app delegate and save the exception into a file. When the log file exists at start up, ask the user to send it to you or upload it in the background. You can also use reporting services like crashlytics

Comment: You're leaking memory here. "imgPicker=nil" will not release the image picker. Instead you need "self.imgPicker=nil" or "[imgPicker release]". This wouldn't cause your crash however.